# Can I set more than one breakpoint on the same line in IntelliJ?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I would like to add two breakpoints on the same line in IntelliJ: one always logs a message, and the other suspends the program if a certain condition is true.

Is this somehow possible to do in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to have two breakpoints on the same line currently.
A workaround - log and check inside breakpoint condition:
here we log `depth` on every hit, but stop only if `depth % 10 == 0`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible.
Right click on breakpoint and then click *More*, or by shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> which opens **Breakpoints** dialog where you need to set up following options:

- Condition
- Evaluate and log

[image]

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't allow me to add two breakpoints on the same line. I want one unconditional logging breakpoint, and one conditional breakpoint that suspends the program.